# Definition of measurable space - sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> A measurable space is a set $S$, together with a nonempty collection,
>   $\mathcal{S}$, of subsets of $S$ satisfying the following two
>   conditions:
>
> 1. For any $A$, $B$ in the collection of $\mathcal{S}$, the set $A-B$ is also in $\mathcal{S}$
> 2. For any $A_1, A_2, ... \in \mathcal{S}$, their union is in $\mathcal{S}$.

[Source](http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/geroch-measures.pdf)

Is $\mathcal{S}$ a sigma algebra? The definition of sigma algebra states it's a collection of subsets of $X$ closed under countable union, complementation, and that it contains the empty set.

Point 1. guarantees it contains the empty set, point 2. states its closed under countable union. But how 1. and 2. imply that it's closed under complement? How to prove that $\mathcal{S}$ contains $S$ as well, as it should (because it contains the empty set), given it really is a sigma-algebra?

Comment: In your 2nd paragraph you say "complementation" and in your 3rd paragraph you say "countable complement". I don't know what "countable complement" means. Did you intend to write "countable intersection"?

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra is a *collection* of subsets of $X$.

Comment: Consider $S=\{1,2\}$ with $\mathcal{S}=\{\{1\},\emptyset\}$.  Or, better yet, $S=\{1\}$ and $\mathcal{S}=\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Worth noting that all the examples from the cited document place $S$ in $\mathcal{S}$ by fiat as there is no way to do so from (1.) and (2.).

Comment: 1) and 2) do *not* guarantee that the collection is closed under complementation and (equivalently) do *not* guarantee that the collection contains $S$.

Comment: I wouldn't take the "Source" too seriously; you may or may not have noticed the author is not entirely familiar with Lebesgue integration (otherwise it is hard to explain the misspelling of the name).

Comment: @mathguy: Many people who *ARE* familiar with Lebesgue integration misspell the name as "Lebesque". Indeed, this error occurs throughout the literature (published books, research papers, etc.) for many decades. I started noticing it around 1992 when I was doing some literature searches connected with my dissertation, and ever since then I've wondered just what it is that makes "Lebesque" so attractive. Try searching for "Lebesque" and "measure" (separate words, not phrase) in google-books and google-scholar, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal S$ is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra.

For instance let $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $\mathcal S=\wp(\{1,2,3\}$).

Then $\mathcal S$ satisfies the conditions, but $\{1,2,3,4\}\notin\mathcal S$.

$\mathcal S$ is a so-called [$\sigma$-ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ring).

---

**edit**:

Another example inspired by the comment of Samuel and emphasizing that there is an essential difference:

Let $S$ be an uncountable set and let $\mathcal S$ denote the collection of countable subsets of $S$.

Note that in this case (unlike the one above) the collection cannot be identified as a $\sigma$-algebra on a subset of $S$.

Comment: However it is a $\sigma$-algebra on a subset of $S$. Need this be the case?

Comment: Does it mean the definition given in this documemt is wrong?

Comment: @user4205580 It can happen that measures are defined on collections like these. So it goes too far to say that the document is wrong.

Comment: @SamuelCoskey No. Take for instance the collection of countable subsets of an uncountable set.

Comment: I have added a link.

Comment: @user4205580 This so-called "definition" is definitely wrong. As drhab has shown the conditions are not sufficient to conclude that $\cal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and that is required for a "measurable space."

Comment: @drhab - Is there more than one accepted definition of measurable space? I taught PhD level courses in this stuff and I have only ever seen one definition. If anyone wants to generalize the concept, I think that's fine, but they would have to invent their own terminology, right?

Comment: @mathguy Well, a look at the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ring) will tell you one another. Especially under "uses". No reason for panic, though. Just stick to $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: I don't see the connection. I said "definition of **measurable space**" - I see nothing about measurable spaces in what you pointed to.

Comment: Actually, I take it back - now I followed your suggestion to look under uses, and it reinforces what I said. One would use $\sigma$-rings if they do NOT wish to require the universal space to be measurable!

Comment: It is not unthinkable  that working along these lines spaces equipped with $\sigma$-rings will be called measurable spaces.Mathematicians can be sloppy when it comes to terminology.

Comment: On that I will have to strongly disagree - my first career was as a research mathematician in three different countries (and actually on three different continents), and sloppiness, when it did rear its head, was always unintentional and immediately addressed. It is definitely not something mathematicians turn a blind eye to.

Comment: @mathguy That sounds good. Maybe I was too much looking at myself when I (mis?)judged mathematicians ;). When I encounter something of measurable spaces equipped with $\sigma$-rings (and not at the same time $\sigma$-algebra) then I will let you know. Maybe sloppy is not the right word, but stubborn. If "raised" in some theory (there are different "schools") and later meeting a parallel with some different terminology then there is no eagerness to switch.